# The results after each training keras model are different

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm a newbie in Machine Learning. I want to build a keras model which will be used for facial recognition. I am currently using the model at:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
             input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# initiate RMSprop optimizer
opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)

# Let's train the model using RMSprop
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=opt,
           metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I trained with the same data and parameters the same, but the training results are very different.There are 100% results or 28% results.
What made that difference?

Comment: Each training iteration would cause a weight update in the model. A change in weights would cause the model to perform differently which caused the difference in the training result.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion @Edwin

Comment: The model is initialized with random weights at the beginning of training, so each time you train, you will arrive at a different local minima, producing different results. This is normal and not a programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the seed, when training the model will solve the problem. This will give you the repeatability.

```
np.random.seed(10)
tf.set_random_seed(10)
```

Also make sure train and test split also does not change ever instance. Hence, you can set the seed for data splitting also.

Comment: It seems my knowledge is too little about machine learning. Thanks for your suggesstion @AILearning

Comment: If you do not mind, Can you recommend me a python and keras training model for applying face recognition to reality? The model I was looking for and tried unidentifiable use of my face and it always confused with other people in the data. My data is only three people –

Comment: @desertnaut I'm looking for related theories and try to fix them under suggestions. If this is the answer I will go back and confirm